# Xcode signing error No signing Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Having recently updated my Mac, I have had lots of login problems, eventually when I was able to login, Xcode is giving me the error:

> No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "L435GR2VGD" with a private key was found.

How can add a private key to a cert?

Comment: You can't recreate a private key (by design -- this is critical to the security of the public/privake key system). Do you have a backup?

Answer (score 1):

One option is if you have it exported to imported in the keychain.
But most probably you don't have it and you should generate new one in developer.apple.com > Cerificates